# Tabless tab control to emulate java's Card Layout Manager

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, tabcontrol

I want to emulate java's card Layout Manager in C#. From what I can tell, with out buying 3rd party software, the easiest way to do this is with a tab control that I set up each tab as I see fit with components and then in the TabControl properties window set:

TabControl.Appearance = Buttons

TabControl.SizeMode = Fixed

TabControl.ItemSize = 0,1

TabControl.Alignment = Top

This will give me a "tabless" tab control (tab control with out any tabs).  This will allow me to control the order in which the user "flips" through the different tabs.

This works, but anytime I use a control in a non standard way, I feel that it is hacky and prone to problems.  Is this a good way to go about this, or is this "Amature C# GUI developement hour" material?

Thanks

Comment: Run it and hit Ctrl+Tab, decide if you want your users to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first reaction is, "if the properties are there for you to change, then change them". You are not hacking into anything to change functionality - you are modifying functionality using the provided public properties.

The only thing I would recommend is to create a `UserControl` to encapsulate your custom *tabless* TabControl. Otherwise, if the changes you propose will provide you with the emulated functionality you need, then it's a good way to do it. Nothing about your changes seem 'hackish' or in bad form.

**Edit**
Based on @Henk's comment: I *don't* feel it is hackish to customize an existing control to a point. I hadn't thought of the side effects of something like Ctrl+Tab. If you have to start writing work-arounds to deal with existing functionality, then it is probably time to look for another control (such as @minitech links to, very nice BTW), or open up VS, create a new UserControl and start to work. Often, though, you will find a control to fit your needs.

Comment: I would say trying to use a TabControl as something else is a form of hacking. And the devil is in the details (like Ctrl+Tab). Lots of subtle behaviour built into these controls.

Comment: @Henk: It is still a TabControl, though. Of course, it comes down to the side affects of the changes the OP makes. If the affects are not worth the effort to elegantly work with, and you have to start finding work-arounds (such as what to do with Ctrl+Tab), then it starts getting hackish.

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=558143 for a pre-built tabless tab control. It's in VB.NET but there are plenty of converters and you could also compile it if you have a VB.NET compiler.

Answer (score 0):

you can use cardlayout component from Syncfusion controls package
for more information check this address :

---

http://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/asp.net%20mvc/chart/html/177b5fe2-fa6d-061d-5cc3-18048081a494.htm

although this package is not free but can be usefull for professional programming

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.